# Smart cast to 'Bitmap!' is impossible, because 'bitmap1' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time

Tags: kotlin

```
     bitmap1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(

        bitmap1, // <---- error is  here 

        (width.toInt()),

        (height.toInt()),

        false)

    numberOfInvaders ++
```

I also used bitmap2 and bitmap 1  in another class :

```
                 if (uhOrOh) {
                    canvas.drawBitmap(Invader.bitmap1, // <--- error is here 
                        invader.position.left,
                        invader.position.top,
                        paint)
                } else {
                    canvas.drawBitmap(Invader.bitmap2, // <---- and here
                        invader.position.left,
                        invader.position.top,
                        paint)
                }
```

here its says : Type mismatch,
                Required:Bitmap  Found: Bitmap?

Comment: It expects a non-null bitmap (so a `Bitmap`), but `bitmap1` is nullable (so a `Bitmap?`)

Comment: so what i have to do to fix it ? im kinda new

Comment: Figured it out  just needed to add !! next to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, that's true :) You cannot use value like this, because it can be null at some point.

`createScaledBitmap` requires nonnullable `Bitmap`, but there is no guarantee that bitmap you use won't be null at the moment of calling given function.

So, what you can do?
Before the call check if bitmap is not null:

```
if (bitmap != null) { /* code here, still requires !! operator */ }
```

In multithreaded environment there is a risk that during execution of code block a value will change anyway, so you can use `let` function with `?.` operator (basically the same operator like `.`, but executes only if value is not null). The block code will be invoked with an effectively final argument which is an instance you use to call this method, in this case "bitmap", called "context object", accessible via `it` keyword:

```
bitmap?.let { /* code here, bitmap is passed as effectively final, so for sure it's not null  */ }
```

There other way would be `!!` operator (but it can finish with NPE exception, if value is null). Use only if you are sure that this value at that moment won't be null, otherwise you can crash your application.

Also, you can use `?:` operator - this will take first value if not null, otherwise the second. It's quite nice, because you can use for example default value. Also, you can throw exception there ;)

```
bitmap ?: throw IllegalStateException("bitmap is null") // exception
bitmap ?: DEFAULT_BITMAP // default bitmap, if any
```

In this case you will get exception but with very communicative message (instead of just NPE).

Comment: `?.let` doesn’t make smart casting possible, but it gives you a non-nullable value to use instead of the nullable one.

Answer (score 0):

```
    bitmap1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(

    bitmap1!!, // !! <--- helps

    (width.toInt()),

    (height.toInt()),

    false)

numberOfInvaders ++



            if (uhOrOh) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(Invader.bitmap1!!, //  here 
                    invader.position.left,
                    invader.position.top,
                    paint)
            } else {
                canvas.drawBitmap(Invader.bitmap2!!, //  and here too
                    invader.position.left,
                    invader.position.top,
                    paint)
            }
```